# Multiple datetimePickers on 1 HTML page not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use multiple dateTime pickers on my HTML page to capture "start date" and "end date".

See my HTML below.

```
<Head>
    <!-- LINKS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
          $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
    <title>MyPage</title>
</head>
```

And here is the body

```
<body>
 <div class='col-8'>
        <h1 class="mt-2">Date Form</h1>
        <hr class="mt-0 mb-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The first datetime picker works fine, but the on the second datetime picker the button to load the calendar doesn't work. Can someone suggest whats wrong with the code?

Comment: ID's are for singular elements. If you want to create a generic datepicker with a certain set of rules - use classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialize second datetime picker

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
      $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker(); // <<<<< add this line 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because you only instantiate the datetimepicker on the `#datetimepicker1` element.

If you want to have the control on both of them, try using a class selector instead:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.input-group.date').datetimepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='col-8'>
  <h1 class="mt-2">Date Form</h1>
  <hr class="mt-0 mb-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
      <input type='text' class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
      <input type='text' class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```